# Scraping single page websites

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I want to get data from bet365.com, but the problem is that when I download page-source, page-source doesn't contain that data. As I searched, in single page application everything is not loaded immediately. I tried following code but coudn't get desired data. can anyone help?

```
    public string GetGeneratedHTML(string url)
    {
        URL = url;
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WebBrowserThread));
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
        t.Join();

        return GeneratedSource;
    }

    private void WebBrowserThread()
    {
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.Navigate(URL);

        wb.DocumentCompleted +=
            new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(
                wb_DocumentCompleted);

        while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            Application.DoEvents();

        //Added this line, because the final HTML takes a while to show up
        GeneratedSource = wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml;

        wb.Dispose();
    }`enter code here`

    private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender,
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
        GeneratedSource = wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml;
    }
```

Comment: Seems bet365 does not like scrapers

Comment: Also, could not find in page source that pieces of code what i see on  site

Answer (score 3):

Use the Network tab of your browser's dev tools to see what REST endpoints they call to get data. Then instead of scraping the html call the endpoints directly and get the data.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks.. almost feel dumb not thinking about this but your comment put me on the right track.  Was trying to justify instantiating selenium based docker container in the project to get the rendered source as a service but figured I would do some research first.  The SPA I'm trying to grab indeed does a REST call which I was able to isolate in the network tab.. lol, perfect.  Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting up a delay event/timer to check the page for the availability of the new data/html. Then use your own functions written like you have wb_DocumentCompleted essentially. Not terribly efficient, but very accurate. Good luck!..

```
protected System.Timers.Timer MonitorTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
public void Initialize()
{
    MonitorTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(UpdateEvent);
    MonitorTimer.Interval = 1000;
    MonitorTimer.Enabled = true;
}
protected object TimerLock = new object();
public void UpdateEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lock (TimerLock)
    {
        doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)wbProfile.Document;
        // What you are looking for that only appears later. -->
        if(doc.body.innerHTML.toString().IndexOf("foo") != -1) 
        {
            // Do something useful..
        }
    }
}
```